# How to concatenate paths returned from `fileset` into the XML file?

Tags: ant, path, fileset

I'm trying to concatenate an unknown number of HTML files into one XML file.
That's no problem with:

```
<concat destfile="${temp.dir}/file.xml" encoding="UTF-8" outputencoding="UTF-8">
    <fileset dir="${html.dir}" includes="**/*.html" />
</concat>
```

Now what I would like to do is, for each file of the `fileset`, insert its path into the concatenated file.

### Example

I have the following HTML files in `C:\whatever\sources`:

- A.html
- B.html

In the result XML file, I'd like to get:

```
  <allfiles>
   <html url="C:\whatever\sources\A.html>...content of A.html...</html>
   <html url="C:\whatever\sources\B.html>...content of B.html...</html>
  </allfiles>
```

Is there a way to do that simply without reinventing the wheel and if possible without using `ant-contrib`?

Comment: See the answer from Martin Clayton in [Getting file name inside Ant copy task filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376795/getting-file-name-inside-ant-copy-task-filter/4377913#4377913). Although that answer uses `<copy>`, a `<scriptfilter>` can also be used with `<concat>`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, seems impossible without using ant-contrib then? mmh :(

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846169/how-to-concatenate-paths-returned-from-fileset-into-the-xml-file#comment53526981_32846169), you can use a `scriptfilter` inside `filterchain` task to run Javascript inside your Ant build.

For example:

```
<concat destfile="${temp.dir}/file.xml" encoding="UTF-8" outputencoding="UTF-8">
    <fileset dir="${html.dir}" includes="**/*.html" id="my-files"/>
    <filterchain>
        <tokenfilter>
            <filetokenizer />
                 <scriptfilter language="javascript" byline="false"><![CDATA[
                     content = self.getToken();
                     // Modify content of token.
                     //content=content.replaceAll("(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/","");
                     self.setToken(content);
            ]]></scriptfilter>
        </tokenfilter>
        <striplinecomments>
            <comment value="//"/>
        </striplinecomments>
        <striplinebreaks/>
    </filterchain>
</concat>
```

Find more examples at:

- [`JavaExplorer/blob/master/static/build.xml`](https://github.com/chenyuelin/JavaExplorer/blob/master/static/build.xml)
- [Getting file name inside Ant copy task filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4376795/55075)
- [Using Ant scriptfilter to count lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3695585/55075)